# Magento : the cart is always empty

Tags: magento, cart

I've been looking for several days now and the problem is stil there. 
I'm running the following version of Magento :1.9.0.1
I do not experience any particular problem on local (using Mamp). But on my production server my cart page (beginning of the checkout process) is always empty no matter the number of items i try to add inside my cart.
I tried lots of different solution posted on many websites but nothing seems to solve it (since this is working on local it  might be a server configuration problem).
Any suggestion ?
Thank you 
(Ps: English is not my main language so i'm sorry for the poor syntaxe).

Comment: Are you sure you have exported all the tables  to the production environment?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to login to the site?

Just check in the backend. System->Configuration->Web->Session cookie management

Whether there is a wrong value set for cookie domain

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Already tried with value (86400 and 0). Not working

Comment: what is the value for cookie domain there?

Comment: just try it with the domain value. Doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The problem was related to a theme template module. I remove the module and it's working now.
Ty